# How can speaking and listening in English work?

Tags: listening, spoken-english

For example, you say to me

> My eye is sick

But I heard

> My I is sick

I have read a 'homonym' article but it just show the words that have same sound on speaking. How to distinguish one word with another that has the same sound?

Comment: All languages have ambiguously sounding combinations of words. You distinguish the true intent of the speaker fromt the overall context. The sentence "My I is sick" is a very odd sentence. "My eye is sick" is less odd. "My eye hurts" is evel less odd.

Comment: Context, common sense, perceived speaker intent, concatenation...

Comment: "My I is sick" is an ungrammatical utterance.  The ungrammaticalness steers the listener away from that parsing. (**My** does not take a pronoun in the nominative case as complement, unless the pronoun is somehow coerced into a nominal by a special case, e.g. if Freud had said "The 'I'" instead of "The *ego*". But then it would be as if the pronoun were enclosed in quotation marks, and it would receive different intonation when spoken. Intonation patterns also guide the listener.)

Comment: @TRomano: I don't see why **I** can't be used to mean something like **ego** (as in *My ego is deflated*). Since it's completely unnatural to say things like *My tongue is sick* anyway, I wouldn't leap to that interpretation if I thought the sentence had been uttered by a competent speaker. In fact, the only credible interpretation I can tthink of if we assume a competent speaker is *My **ai** is sick* (my pet three-toed sloth is unwell).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. You have to read more carefully, or beyond the first sentence. Nowhere did I say that **I** "cannot be used to mean something like **ego**". In fact, I said just the opposite.

Comment: @TRomano: Again with the indignant refutation! We have *no idea* what intonation a speaker might place on the text as given, so it's stretching a point to say the text is "ungrammatical". All we can say is that it's ***non-idiomatic*** except in the (admittedly, unlikely) context where ***I*** is a misspelling of ***ai***.

Comment: It is actually ungrammatical except in what TRomano has called special cases.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  We do indeed have *an idea* of the intonation that would be given to the word **I** if it were being used to mean *the ego* as in the phrase "my *I*".  Listen to the parsing rhythms of native speakers when they put scare quotes around a word or phrase.  Native speakers advisedly and intentionally doing such a thing will bracket the "quoted" phrase with pauses and change theintonation in some manner to mark the usage.

Comment: @TRomano: I think what you mean is *you* have an idea how *you* would  enunciate the text if *you* were trying to convey the sense you've already decided upon. But I see nothing in OP's question text that guides us in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being able to distinguish homonyms in speech is something you need to practice. Once you get familiar with English, you'll be able to understand which word people mean based on the context.

For example:

Bob says to Anne

> I had a great vacation last fall

There are multiple meanings for fall (even written the same way): 1. the season Fall, between summer and winter; or 2. to fall, where you trip or otherwise make contact with the ground in an unpreferred way.

Anne knows that you cannot have a vacation while falling down, but you can have a vacation during the season of fall. She understands that Bob means that he went on a vacation during this season.

**In summary:** There is no definitive guide to understanding which word people mean while speaking, while you learn English you will understand that some words are more probable in a certain context, compared to others.